# Mudblazor Select shrinking on selecting

Tags: css, flexbox, mudblazor

I have two select controls and a button. The select seems to be shrinking once an option is selected. I have reproduced the issue here:

[snippet link](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOwxuKbSoSvBLNqE)

This is the relevant code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-space-between mx-2">
        <MudGrid>
            <MudItem xs="12" md="4" sm="4">
                    <MudSelect T="string" Label="From Language" @bind-Value="@fromLanguage" Variant="Variant.Filled" Style="min-width: 200px;" FullWidth="true" Dense="true" DisableUnderLine="true" Class="et-select-input d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">
                    @foreach (var language in languages)
                    {
                        <MudSelectItem Value="@language">@language</MudSelectItem>
                    }
                </MudSelect>
            </MudItem>
                <MudItem xs="12" md="4" sm="4">
                    <MudSelect T="string" Label="To Language" @bind-Value="@toLanguage" Variant="Variant.Filled" Dense="true" Style="min-width: 200px;" FullWidth="true" DisableUnderLine="true" Class="et-select-input d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">
                    @foreach (var language in languages)
                    {
                        <MudSelectItem Value="@language">@language</MudSelectItem>
                    }
                </MudSelect>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem>
                    <MudButton Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary" Class="py-14 d-flex flex-1" >Do something</MudButton>
            </MudItem>
        </MudGrid>
</div>
@code {

    private List<string> languages = new List<string> { "English", "Spanish", "French", "German", "Dutch" };
    private string fromLanguage = "";
    private string toLanguage = "";

    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I notice the same behaviour in Mudblazor's official page as well:
[Here](https://mudblazor.com/components/select#value-presentation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `align-center` from your `MudSelect`.

```
<MudSelect T="string" Label="From Language" @bind-Value="@fromLanguage" Variant="Variant.Filled" Style="min-width: 200px;" FullWidth="true" Dense="true" DisableUnderLine="true" 
    Class="et-select-input py-8">
        //
</MudSelect>
```

[Mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuGdEUlgdABkHmQC)